# Boolean variable does not change to false

Tags: apex, visualforce

for some reason the proc variable is always being true.... I must be wrong in something simple... if anyone knows, please tell me, and I apologize if this question is silly

```
Controller:

 for(OpportunityContactRole i: aluno){
   if(i.contact.Procurador__r.Dado__c!=null){
            String formatted = formata(i.contact.Procurador__r.Dado__c);
            i.contact.Procurador__r.Dado__c=formatted; 
            proc=true;
        }else{
            proc=false;
        }       
    }}
```

VisualForce Page:

```
<table>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Aluno:</td>
                        </tr>   
                        <tr>
                            <td>{!item.Name}</td>
                        </tr> 
                        <apex:outputText rendered="{!proc}">
                            <tr><td> {!item.contact.Procurador__r.Dado__c}</td></tr>
                            <tr><td> {!item.contact.Procurador__r.Dado2__c}</td></tr>
                            <tr><td>var proc: {!proc}</td></tr><!--when generating this vfp the proc variable always comes out true-->
                       </apex:outputText>    
                    </tbody>      
                </table>
```

---

Comment: Are you trying to show a list of records? Or, does the field `Dado__c` have a default value?

Comment: List of records @sfdcfox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To display each record individually, you need to have one Boolean per record. I'd use a map to minimize the refactoring you'd have to do:

```
public Map<Id, Boolean> display { get; set; }
```

...

```
display = new Map<Id, Boolean>();
```

...

```
display.put(i.Id, i.contact.Procurador__r.Dado__c!=null);
if(i.contact.Procurador__r.Dado__c!=null){
        String formatted = formata(i.contact.Procurador__r.Dado__c);
        i.contact.Procurador__r.Dado__c=formatted;
    } 
}
```

...

```
<apex:outputText rendered="{!display[item.Id]}">
```

Comment: Note: I'm currently mobile. I'll amend this answer if necessary when I get back home.

Comment: Thak you, it worked here @sfdcfox

Comment: @Carolyne You're welcome!